# How do I use .htaccess rewrite to remove the first item from a url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a url like this:

```
www.example.com/best-sellers/mistery/novels/this-is-a-book-title
```

That first item (best-sellers) is always the uppermost parent. I don't really have any content for the uppermost parent of any of my pages and I don't have a need for that to be in the url. However, the url is based on the menu structure (of which I have little control over).

I would like to remove the first item from the url even though I don't know what it will be. It could be best-seller, new-items, reader-favorites, etc.

Can I accomplish this through an htaccess rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the browser to a URI that doesn't have the first path item, you can use this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1
```

Or, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This would need to be in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: though this appears to work... drupal doesn't like it. Not saying you're wrong but the CMS goes bananas.

Comment: @dcp3450 are you using the rewrite rule but before any drupal related rules in your htaccess?